# Erro Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, para um select

Tags: java, mysql, select

O meu sistema, no botao salvar, inseri 3 tabelas ao mesmo tempo, sendo que 2 utiliza FK, estou usando o campo cad_id como FK em 2 tabelas, estou fazendo um select para pegar no banco um unico campo cad_id para salvar nas outras 2 tabelas, usando o resultset, para setar um objeto do sistema, e esta mostrando este erro ja olhei em varios foruns e inclusive em ingles, abaixo segue o codigo.

```
public void selecionaSalvar(String nome){

        String sql = "select cad_id from cadastro where cad_nome = '"+nome+"';";

        ResultSet rset = null;


        try {

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);


            rset = stmt.executeQuery();

            Ficha fc =new Ficha();//instancia da classe principal

            if(rset.isFirst()){
                fc.setChaveFKBanco(rset.getInt("cad_id"));
            }
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException u) {
            throw new RuntimeException(u);
        }
    }
```

ja utilizei while(rset.next()) e while(!rset.next()), ja utilizei if(rset.next()) e if(!rset.next()), ja utilizei first(), beforefirst(), queria saber onde estaria o erro
desde ja agradeco

Comment: Já tentou executar essa sql direto no banco pra ver o retorno?

Comment: É nessa parte mesmo que esta retornando erro? Pela mensagem parece que esta esperando um campo chamado "count" e não "cad_id".

Comment: ja sim, me trouxe o numero certo,so quando fiz a classe DAO que esta mostrando este erro.